# Multiply every 3rd element in the existing array

Tags: ruby

How to multiply every 3rd element in the existing array.

The code below gives me the following output `[6, 12, 18, 24]` as expected.

But how to update values in `myArr` without creating new array:
`[1,2,6,4,5,12,7,8,18,10,11,24,13,14]`

```
myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

res = myArr[2].step(myArr.length-1, 3).map{|val| val*2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this does it:

```
0.upto(myArr.length - 1) {|i| myArr[i] *= 2 if i % 3 == 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myArr.each_index{|i| myArr[i] *= 2 if i% 3 == 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more solution in addition to Paul's answer:

```
myArr.map!.with_index{|k,i| i % 3 == 2 ? k * 2 : k }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
factor = 2
every = 3

((every-1)...arr.size).step(every) { |i| arr[i] *= factor }
arr #=> [1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]
```

Another way:

```
mult = ([1]*(every-1)).push(fac).cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1,1,2].cycle>
arr.map! { |e| e*mult.next }
  #=> [1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]
```